# Problems using Json.NET to load json with variables names

Tags: json.net

My issue is to load the json in this URL with Json.NET: http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=il&p=5399

Here is an abbreviated sample of the JSON for reference:

```
{
    "0": {
        "lat": "-30.03087344108400000",
        "lng": "-51.22585742359100000"
    },
    "1": {
        "lat": "-30.03094644108400000",
        "lng": "-51.22480142359100000"
    },
    "2": {
        "lat": "-30.03099144108400000",
        "lng": "-51.22434242359100000"
    },
    "190": {
        "lat": "-30.11229544108400000",
        "lng": "-51.24937242359100000"
    },
    "191": {
        "lat": "-30.11159444108400000",
        "lng": "-51.24973042359100000"
    },
    "idlinha": "5399",
    "nome": "CAMAQUA ",
    "codigo": "173-2"
}
```

The value into `RoteBus.rote` is always empty.
Could anybody help me?

I'm using the code:

```
 WebClient webClient2 = new WebClient();
 webClient2.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(itinerario);
 webClient2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=il&p=5399"));
 void itinerario(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

    RoteBus rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoteBus>(e.Result);
    Debug.WriteLine("rootObject.rote = " + rootObject.rote);
 }

 public class Rote
 {
     public string lat { get; set; }
     public string lng { get; set; }
 }

 public class RoteBus
 {
     public string idlinha { get; set; }
     public string nome { get; set; }
     public string codigo { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, Rote> rote { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: The JSON doesn't have a "rote" object. Or "idlinha", "nome", or "codingo" for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the variable `Rote` data is mixed in with the fixed properties of the `RoteBus`, you are going to need a custom `JsonConverter` class to make this work.  Here is one way to write it:

```
public class RoteBusConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(RoteBus));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        RoteBus rb = new RoteBus { rote = new Dictionary<string, Rote>() };
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "idlinha") 
                rb.idlinha = prop.Value.ToString();
            else if (prop.Name == "nome") 
                rb.nome = prop.Value.ToString();
            else if (prop.Name == "codigo") 
                rb.codigo = prop.Value.ToString();
            else 
                rb.rote.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToObject<Rote>());
        }
        return rb;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `RoteBus` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RoteBusConverter))]
public class RoteBus
{
    ...
}
```

Then deserialize as usual:

```
RoteBus rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoteBus>(e.Result);
```